# Unable to create Event Handler WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, event-handling

I am unable to create Event Handler when i double click on button or anything this messagebox appears
[image]

how ever when i add event handler manually it works.any idea what might have i screwed up
thanks

Comment: yes but coudent understand it what it wants.in which file?actully i am new to wpf so i am so much confsed

Comment: Did you check what is actually asked in the message: that your class `MainWindow` is the first class in the appropriate .cs file? The IDE somehow needs this for modifying the source code (don't know why).

Comment: Yes thanks guys it worked there was another class declared on top in CS file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The class in question is the "MainWindow" class within you `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file.  Make sure it's the first class in the code behind file.

I suspect you added another type to that file, and defined it at the top.  It will "break" the designer, and give you this error message.

Answer (score 2):

> Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try again.

Answer (score 2):

there was another class on top of main window in .CS file that is why it was doing problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have renamed the window make sure it has affected to the code behind file too as you can see in the xaml designer code. Compare the class name and window name all the places. I had the same issue and noticed when I renamed the window the associated code behind class name didn't automatically updated. So I did it manually and it was gone for good. Hope this helps :)